# Show that $C^\infty$ is dense in the space of weakly differentiable $L^p$-functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, convolution

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, $T>0$, $I:=(0,T)$, $X,Y$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach spaces and $\iota$ be a continuous embedding of $X$ into $Y$.

If $p\in[1,\infty]$, say $f\in\mathcal L^1(I,X)$ has a weak derivative in $L^p(I,Y)$ if there is a $g\in\mathcal L^p(I,Y)$ with $$\int_I\varphi'\iota f\:{\rm d}\lambda=-\int_I\varphi g\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I).$$ In that case, $f':=g$.

If $p,q\in[1,\infty]$, let $E^{p,\:q}(I)$ denote the space of all $f\in\mathcal L^p(I,X)$ which admit a weak derivative in $L^q(I,Y)$. Moreover, let $$\left\|f\right\|_{E^{p,\:q}}:=\left\|f\right\|_{L^p(I,\:X)}+\left\|f'\right\|_{L^p(I,\:Y)}\;\;\;\text{for }f\in E^{p,\:q}.$$

> How can we show that if $p,q\in[1,\infty)$, then $C^\infty(I,X)$ is a dense subset of $E^{p,\:q}$?

There is a proof of this claim in [*Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-5975-0) (Lemma II.5.10):

[image: Lemma II.5.10]

The mentioned corollary is the (easy to verify) fact that $$\forall r\in[1,\infty):\forall g\in L^r(I,X):\left\|g\circ\tau_h-g\right\|_{L^r(I,\:X)}\xrightarrow{h\to\infty}0\tag2,$$ where $$\tau_h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;a\mapsto a+h$$ for $h\in\mathbb R$.

> I don't understand the argumentation in the proof. How can we give a rigorous proof? And can we even find a suitable subspace "$E_0^{p,\:q}(I)$" of $E^{p,\:q}$ s.t. $C_{\color{red}c}^\infty(I,X)$ is dense in $E_0^{p,\:q}(I)$?

Let $f\in E^{p,\:q}(I)$. We can clearly find $0\le\theta_i\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ (note that I'm not taking $\theta_i\in C^\infty(I)$ as in the book excerpt, since I think we need to $\theta_i$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb R$ in what follows, but please let me know in the comments if I'm missing something) with $\theta_1+\theta_2=1$ and $\operatorname{supp}\theta_1\subseteq\left[0,\frac23T\right]$, $\operatorname{supp}\theta_2\subseteq\left[\frac13T,T\right]$ (although I'm not sure why exactly we need to consider these $\theta_i$).

Now let $$g:=\begin{cases}\theta_1f&\text{on }I\\0&\text{on }\mathbb R\setminus I.\end{cases}$$ I'm not sure whether this will be important, but we should be able to show that $g\in E^{p,\:q}(\mathbb R)$ and $g'=\theta_1f'+\theta_1'\iota f$. Now let $\eta$ be a "mollifying kernel", i.e.

1. $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\operatorname{supp}\eta\subseteq(-1,1)$;
2. $\eta\ge0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\eta=1$;
3. $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R:|x|=|y|\Rightarrow\eta(x)=\eta(y),$

and set $$\eta_\varepsilon(x):=\frac1\varepsilon\eta\left(\frac x\varepsilon\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d.$$ Note that $$g_h:=g\circ\tau_h\in L^p(\mathbb R)$$ and $$g_{h,\:\varepsilon}:=g_h\ast\eta_\varepsilon\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$$ for all $h\in\mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Now, if I got the comment from daw in the comments below right, the idea is to show that $$\left\|g_{h,\:\varepsilon}-g\right\|_{E^{p,\:q}}\le\left\|g_h-g\right\|_{E^{p,\:q}}+\left\|g_{h,\:\varepsilon}-g_h\right\|_{E^{p,\:q}}\to0;\tag1$$ most probably as $h$ and $\varepsilon$ tend to $0$ (right?).

However, the only things which are clear to me are $$\left\|g_h-g\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\xrightarrow{h\to0}0\tag2$$ and $$\forall h\in\mathbb R:\left\|g_{h,\:\varepsilon}-g_h\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\to0+}0\tag3.$$

And even if we can show $(1)$, how does the claim for $f$ follow from that? From Jose27's comment below I suppose that there must be something crucial with the endpoints ...

Comment: $v$ should be $u$, $v_h = v \circ \tau_h$, the final estimate is by triangle inequality: $\|u-v_{h,\epsilon}\|\le \|u-v_h\|+\|v_h - v_{h,\epsilon}\|$, I guess

Comment: These things are also proven in John Hunter's PDE lecture notes, which are freely available.

Comment: At the beginning of the second paragraph of the screenshot, it's said that $v=\theta_1u$, so $v$ is the portion of $u$ that only sees the left endpoint. $v_{h,\varepsilon}$ is a regularization of the translation. The reason we need to regularize the shifted $v_h$ instead of $v$ itself, is that the endpoint makes it awkward to average in a neighborhood of it, that's why we move $u$ $h$-units to the left and then average on neighborhoods of size $\varepsilon<h$. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for your comment. I'll try to work things out using your remarks. But could you tell me if you think that we can adopt the proof to show that even $C_c^\infty(I,X)$ is dense in $E^{p,\:q}$ (not only $C^\infty(I,X)$)?

Comment: @daw Thank your remarks. Can you tell me how exactly the convolution is defined here? My "problem" with that is that $v_h$ is only defined on $[0,T]$.

Comment: No, I don't think you'll be able to prove that if $I\neq \mathbb{R}$; the reason is that functions in $C_c^\infty$ will always have value zero at the endpoints of the interval, but that's not true for all functions in $E^{p,q}$.

Comment: @Jose27 Please take note of my edit. Can we give a suitable closed subspace "$E_0^{p,\:q}$" of $E^{p,\:q}$ such that the claim holds for $C_c^\infty$?

Comment: @Jose27 I've updated the question once again. Since I'm interested in the claim of $C^\infty$ being dense in $E^{p,\:q}$ as well and it seems like you know how to answer my remaining questions, it would be great and I would be really thankful if you could provide an answer.

Comment: If you want some additional literature: "Evans, Gariepy - Measure theory and fine properties of functions" chapter 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be borrowing the notation you use in your edit, basically setting $f=\eta_1 u=v$ so that in particular $f\in E^{p,q}$ and $f$ has compact support on $[0,T)$, and so we may as well assume $I=[0,\infty)$.

We need to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $f^\varepsilon\in C^\infty(I)\cap E^{p,q}$ such that $\| f -f^\varepsilon\|_{E^{p,q}} <\varepsilon$. The idea is to produce $h=h(\varepsilon)>0$, $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon,h)>0$ and $f_{h,\delta}\in C^{\infty}\cap E^{p,q}$ with the following properties:

1. $\| f- f_{h}\|_{E^{p,q}}<\varepsilon/2$, and
2. $\| f_h - f_{h,\delta}\|_{E^{p,q}} <\varepsilon/2$.

If we're able to produce such functions, then $f^\varepsilon:= f_{h,\delta}$ gives the desired approximation by the triangle inequality, as you mentioned in your post.

Now, the reason why we introduce the $h$ has more to do with the type of approximation that we're achieving: If we succeed, notice that $f_\varepsilon\in C^\infty(\bar{I})$, i.e. $f_\varepsilon$ is smooth up to the boundary of your interval. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, given that they only mention $C^\infty(I; X)$, but they're proving more. To be fair though, in one dimension, it's actually easier to argue this way owing to the simple geometry of intervals; as opposed to higher dimensions, where smoothness of the boundary plays a role (See for instance the "H=W" result of Meyers-Serrin, and the failure of approximations by smooth functions up to the boundary; both topics are covered briefly in Evans's PDE book).

Now to the proof. Fix $\varepsilon>0$.

We can guarantee 1 by the Corollary in your text, by choosing $h=h(\varepsilon)$ sufficiently small.

Now let $\delta>0$ and consider $\eta_\delta$ a standard mollifier as in your post. Since $f_h: [-h,\infty)\to X$ and $\text{supp}(\eta_\delta)\subset (-\delta, \delta)$, we see that the convolution
$$
f_{h,\delta}:= \eta_\delta* f_h = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \eta_\delta(y) f(x-y)\, dy,
$$
is well defined for $x\geq 0$ as long as $\delta<h$, in other words, $f_{h,\delta}:[0,\infty)\to X$ and arguing as you did we can check that $f_{h,\delta}\in C^\infty(I,X)\cap E^{p,q}$. It remains to obtain the estimate in 2, for an appropriate choice of $\delta$. For this we have two terms to consider:
$$
\| f_h-f_{h,\delta}\|_{L^p(I;X)}, \quad \text{and} \quad \| f_n'-f_{h,\delta}'\|_{L^q(I;Y)}.
$$
The first one we can make smaller than, say, $\varepsilon/4$ by choosing $\delta$ small enough (depending on both $h$ and $\varepsilon$), owing to properties of mollifiers(+). For the second we use that convolution "commutes" with derivatives(*):
$$
(\eta_\delta* f_h)' =  \eta_\delta* (f_h'),
$$
and so the second term can be handled exactly as the first one; possibly making $\delta$ smaller.

(+) More specifically we have: For any $1\leq p <\infty$, $a>0$, $g\in L^p([-a,\infty); X)$ and $\delta<a$, then $\eta_\delta*g$ is well defined and moreover $\| g-g_\delta\|_{L^p([0,\infty);X)} \to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$.

(*) Owing to the mismatch in spaces, let me sketch how we prove this. Recall that we're talking about weak derivatives here, so we need to show that for every $\phi\in C_c^\infty(0,\infty)$ it holds
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^\infty \phi' \iota (\eta_\delta * f_h)\, dt & = - \int_{0}^\infty \phi \eta_\delta * f_h' \, dt \\ &= -\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(t) \eta_\delta(s)f_h'(t-s)\, ds \, dt\\ & =- \int_{\mathbb{R}}\eta_\delta(s)\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(t)f_h'(t-s)\, dt \, ds,   
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the use of Fubini's theorem is justified since $\phi,\eta$ are compactly supported and bounded, while $f_h'$ is in $L^p$ and has compact support. Since $\delta<h$, the last term above can be written as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \eta(s) \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \phi'(t) \iota f_n(t-s)\, dt \, ds,
$$
owing to the definition of $f_h'$ (or more accurately the translate $f_{h-s}'$). Now it's a simple matter or reversing the order of integrals again to get the result.

As for the space $E_0^{p,q}$; it's typically defined as the closure of $C_c^\infty$ in $E^{p,q}$. Sometimes it has nice characterizations in terms of traces, and I suspect this is true in this context, but I don't have a formal proof at the moment.

Edit: This is too long for a comment so I'm putting it here: The way you extend the function doesn't work; the main issue is that you're introducing a discontinuity at $0$, since $\theta_1(0)=1$ by the requirement that $\theta_1+\theta_2=1$ (think about what would happen if you're trying to extend $f=1$ on $I=[0,1]$ for instance). What you could do is extend $f_h$ with a function $\theta_1$ whose support lies on $(-h, 1/3T)$ or something like this, but then you have to track the dependence on $h$ a bit more carefully when you regularize since derivatives will interact with your cut-off function.

In the end, it's mostly a cosmetic change though, the idea is that past $\delta=h$ you're gaining no information on $f$ at all: the regularizations start picking up values that have no relation to $f$. It's fine either way though, as long as you extend the function in the correct way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort so far. Two questions: (a) Are you denoting by $f_\varepsilon$ and $f_h$ different objects? It seems to be the case, since first you write that we need "to find some $f_\varepsilon$" and then it seems like you're denoting by $f_h$ the function $f\circ\tau_h$. (b) Is your $f$ my $g$? And is there a reason why you don't extend it (as I did) to all of $\mathbb R$, but only to $[0,\infty)$ by $0$?

Comment: First, yes, I've changed notation to clarify this a bit. For the second, yes my $f$ is your $g$; and there's no particular reason why I didn't extend it to the line.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I'm just trying to understand what is going on, since I got trouble to obtain a solution on my own. I thought there might be a reason why you didn't extend to the line, since you've argued $\text{supp}(\eta_\delta)\subset (-\delta, \delta)$ and *hence* the convolution would be well-defined "as long as $x\ge0$ and $\delta<h$; but all of this wouldn't be an issue, if $f_h$ would be defined on all of $\mathbb R$, unless I'm missing something. The argumentation in $(+)$ with $g\in L^p([-a,\infty);X)$ would be simpler then as well; so, I thought I'm missing something.

Comment: Apart from this, everything is pretty clear to me. But to be precise: What is clear to me is that for the *extended* function $g\in L^p(\mathbb R,X)$, we can find a function $g^\varepsilon\in C^\infty(\mathbb R,X)\cap E^{p,\:q}(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $\left\|g^\varepsilon-g\right\|_{E^{p,\:q}(\mathbb R)}<\varepsilon$. But I'm still unsure why we can immediately conclude that for our initial function $f$ (defined only on $I$) we can find $f^\varepsilon\in C^\infty(\overline I,X)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I've edited to add a bit on your extension idea.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing effort. It helped me a lot! In the context of this question, aren't we even able to show that products of functions from $C^\infty(I)$ and $H_0^1(\Omega)$ are dense in $C_c^k(I,H_01(\Omega))$? This is proven in the book only for $k=0$. It would be great if you could take a look at the question I've asked for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4164318/47771.